# Angular2 trying to get item in an array before array is populated

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, sharedservices

I have an Angular2 service as follows. I am trying to use this as a shared service between multiple components. If it matters, the components are binding directly to the `public books`, and `selectedBook properties` I want to cache the list of books and the currently selected book on the service and only call populate these on the first call.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class BookService {

    public books: Book[];
    public selectedBook: Book;

    constructor(private http: Http,
        private router: Router) {

        this.http.get('/api/book/list')
            .subscribe(result => this.books = result.json() as Book[]);
    }

    public getBooks() {
        return this.books;
    }

    public setSelectedBook(id) {
        this.selectedBook = this.books.filter(x => x.id == id)[0];
    }
}
```

The problem is that sometimes I'm trying to read the array or call `setSelecteBook(id)` before the array is actually populated, which causes a crash. I have been trying to find an example of how to use Observables, but I can't find a scenario close enough to mine to be able to figure out how to adapt it to solve my problem.

Comment: You need to initialise `books` in the constructor: `this.books = []`

Comment: This only delays the crash past this point. I need something to make it wait for the books array to finish populating and then set the selected book afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialise the array books in the constructor with an empty array.

You can also do a workaround and check the length before accessing the array.

```
public setSelectedBook(id) {
    if(this.books.length > 0) {
        this.selectedBook = this.books.filter(x => x.id == id)[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Typescript doesn't have the safe evaluation operator `?.`

Comment: @ChristopherMoore is correct about the operator. But, I wrote out the null and length check the long way and all it did was cause the app to crash past this point; it is simply not setting the selected book when called. I need something to make it wait for the books[] to finish populating and then set the selected book afterward.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't initialise an array, it just tells the TypeScript compiler that this certain property is of this type. To actually have an array, instead of being `undefined`, you have to initialise it. This way the `filter` function will work:

```
@Injectable()
export class BookService {

    public books: Book[] = [];
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a cleaner solution i would subscribe from your book-detail component for example to the service method getBooksList.

Do the api call using this.bookService.getBooksList and as soon as the array is loaded select the desired book.

Comment: I think I follow what you are saying, but I could use a little code for clarity. Also, I don't want to call to populate the books[] from the server every time the selected book changes.

Comment: You can have a look at this repo of mine, here:
https://github.com/dkiriakakis/ng2-photoalbum

Take a look into /src/app/components/photo-detail.component.ts